# Showing that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=a$, then for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n^{2k}=a^{2k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

$x_n$ is a sequence. The only thing I can do here is just write the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=a$, but that doesn' t seem helpful to me. I tried looking for some inequalities that would help, and the only thing  that I found that I thought could be a little bit helpful, was the reverse triangle inequality, but I don' t know how to use that here.Could you please give some advice or a hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: induction on $k$ is also viable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equality

$$x^n-a^n =(x-a)(x^{n-1} +x^{n-2}a + \dots + a^{n-1})$$

To prove the inequality

$$\vert x^n -a^n \vert \le n \vert x -a\vert \vert \vert 2a \vert^{n-1}$$

valid for $\vert x \vert \le \vert 2a\vert$.

Then apply it for $n=2k$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

This follows immediately, by induction on $k$, from the product rule for limits; if the limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ exist, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n\cdot b_n)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\right).$$

Comment: I would never think of using induction, thanks a lot

Comment: @Britanica in general, whenever you see a proof asking to show a statement for all $n\in\matbb{N}$ and you’re stuck, it’s never a bad idea to think about trying induction.

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate consequence of the continuity of the map $f_n(x)=x^{n}$.

Comment: Is there a way to show this without using continuity ?